# $lookup as into array does not insert into each object of the array

Tags: mongodb

I have source collection like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "0xeAAB59269bD1bA8522E8e5E0FE510F7aa4d47A09",
        "id": "0xeAAB59269bD1bA8522E8e5E0FE510F7aa4d47A09",
        "gameItemsWithQty": [
            {
                "gameItem": { "_id": 1 },
                "qty": 1000
            },
            {
                "gameItem": { "_id": 2 },
                "qty": 1000
            },
            {
                "gameItem": { "_id": 3 },
                "qty": 1000
            },
            {
                "gameItem": { "_id": 4 },
                "qty": 1000
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

and game items collection like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Stamina Refill"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Large Stamina Refill"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "XL Large Stamina Refill"
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Large Stamina Refill"
  }
]
```

When performing lookup from first onto second collection:

```
{
  from: 'game-items',
  localField: 'gameItemsWithQty.gameItem._id',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'gameItemsWithQty.gameItem'
}
```

It nests `gameItem` array into `gameItemsWithQty` field.

```
"_id": ...,
"id": ...,
"gameItemsWithQty": {
  "gameItem": {
    0: ...,
    1: ...,
    2: ...,
    3: ...
  }
}
```

I need it to nest results into each respective `gameItem` object inside of each object in `gameItemsWithQty`.

```
"_id": ...,
"id": ...,
"gameItemsWithQty": {
  0: {
    gameItem: ...
    qty: ...
  },
  1: {
    gameItem: ...
    qty: ...
  },
  ...
}
```

How do I correct this aggregation pipeline to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

1. `$lookup` - Lookup and return the result as `gameItems` array.
2. `$set` - Set `gameItemsWithQty` field.

   2.1. `$map` - Iterate the element in `gameItemsWithQty` array and returns new array.

   2.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current iterate document with the result *2.1.2*.

   2.1.2. Document with `gameItem` field. Merge the result of *2.1.2.1* with the `gameItem` field of current iterate document.

   2.1.2.1. Get the first document (via `$first`) from the filtered array by matching the `_id`s.

```
db.source.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "game-items",
      localField: "gameItemsWithQty.gameItem._id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "gameItems"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      gameItemsWithQty: {
        $map: {
          input: "$gameItemsWithQty",
          as: "gameItemWithQty",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$gameItemWithQty",
              {
                gameItem: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    {
                      $first: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: "$gameItems",
                          cond: {
                            $eq: [
                              "$$gameItemWithQty.gameItem._id",
                              "$$this._id"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "$$gameItemWithQty.gameItem"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "gameItems"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XitAlH46TKm)